# Cannot access Qemu/KVM virtual using console, VNC, or SSH, or access via network (IP range no longer valid)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have the host sitting here next to me, so you'd think I'd have decent control of the guest. I should add that I have already attempted various other means, such as mounting the drive, but I have found installing ndb-client to be nigh impossible without a kernel update. (It's not just a raw .img file powering this virt, it's qcow2).

When entering through VNC, the virtual hangs:

INIT: Id "1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: no more processes left in this runlevel

When entering through console, the virtual hangs:

Connected to domain xxx.xxx.xxx
Escape character is ^]

All of the guides I have read involve making modifications to the file system, which I have no access to. I obviously have no way to use SSH, and I have not found a working way to forward the port to allow access from the HOST->GUEST, though this would likely be the most sound option.

The interfaces configured in /etc/network/interfaces no longer have valid IP's, and I cannot modify them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can attach the disk as a secondary on another VM or you can boot the VM from a live CD.

Comment: Care to add some more detail to this ?

Comment: I have tried this, and it seems so obvious now. For anyone else experiencing this problem, here is the guide I used:

http://mycfg.net/articles/booting-from-a-cdrom-in-a-kvm-guest-with-libvirt.html

Essentially I did a wget from the host node to download Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and placed it in /isos/ubuntu.iso. I then made the necessary modifications using virsh edit <hostname> to affect the boot procedure for the cdrom device, restarted the virtual and connected through VNC.

Thanks!